# Jasmine tests failed : Attempt to use a destroyed view: detectChanges

Tags: angular, jasmine

We have an Angular 8 application. Few of our jasmine tests failed with the following error. It doesn't show which test exactly throws following error. Is there an easy way to find it?

Please note that it happens only when tests are run in **ChromeHeadless** browser.

```
Error: ViewDestroyedError: Attempt to use a destroyed view: detectChanges
at viewDestroyedError (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/C:/code/client/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:28818:1)
at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/C:/code/client/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:45256:1)
at checkAndUpdateView (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/C:/code/client/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:44271:1)
at callWithDebugContext (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/C:/code/client/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:45632:1)
at Object.debugCheckAndUpdateView [as checkAndUpdateView] (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/C:/code/client/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:45194:1)
at ViewRef_.detectChanges (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/C:/code/client/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:31126:1)
at ComponentFixture._tick (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/C:/code/client/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/testing.js:319:1)
at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/C:/code/client/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/testing.js:336:20
at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/C:/code/client/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js:359:1)
at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/C:/code/client/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:308:1), 'Error: ViewDestroyedError: Attempt to use a destroyed view: detectChanges
at viewDestroyedError (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/C:/code/client/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:28818:1)
at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/C:/code/client/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:45256:1)
at checkAndUpdateView (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/C:/code/client/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:44271:1)
at callWithDebugContext (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/C:/code/client/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:45632:1)
at Object.debugCheckAndUpdateView [as checkAndUpdateView] (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/C:/code/client/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:45194:1)
at ViewRef_.detectChanges (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/C:/code/client/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:31126:1)
at ComponentFixture._tick (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/C:/code/client/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/testing.js:319:1)
at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/C:/code/client/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/testing.js:336:20
at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/C:/code/client/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js:359:1)
```

Comment: Can you please share your unit test code as well as the component code that the test is testing against?

Comment: We have around 600 tests. I am not sure which test is throwing this error.

Comment: @abhishek Change your reporter to karma-spec-reporter. it will help to identify which tests are failing

Comment: Thank you @Samdeesh. It helped.

Comment: Can you please share your solution @Abhishek?